# Building ASP.Net custom authorization against database without MVC

Tags: asp.net, security, sharepoint, authorization

this is my first request, so don´t be too hard. :)

We are building an Sharepoint 2010 - Application, which consists of some Sharepoint Web Parts and many ASP.Net-Sites. Therefore we are limited to use ASP.Net without MVC. This decision is made and can´t be refused.

We are using Windows Authentification with Impersonation. The Users are stored in an application database. Along with the users there are roles which have rights to specific objects and specific actions. all these informations are stored in the custom database.

The database has a data access layer (EF 4.0). Because Sharepoint is limited to .NET Framework 3.5, the business logic consists of a WCF Data Service which is using the DAL and business logic libary which accessing the WCF Data Service to grab the required information.

The ASP.Net-Pages and Sharepoint Web Parts are directly accessing the business logic.

What i now need is some kind of a Manager-Class which is checking the user against the database to authorize him to access the specific objects. I dont want to do it programmaticly. I want to use annotations to specify if a method from the business layer can be called or not. Furthermore i want to hide some things in the ASP.Net Sites without an programmaticly if-clause.

Can someone give me a hint to achieve this? Is there a way do customize some part of the standard framework to realize it?

The user and his roles and rights i want to store in a session. Is this a good way? the application is accessible only in local network.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!  A few thoughts on this -

1. You may be better suited to ask these questions at the cousin site http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.
2. This depends on your web farm architecture.  If your web front end and data sources are on the same server, then it should be simple to use windows authentication to determine the current user.  However, if your web front ends and data sources are on separate servers, then you've reached a limitation due to the "double hop" scenario, where the user's credentials cannot be shared to the server behind the sharepoint server - so to speak.
   To work around, investigate using Kerberos authentication in your SharePoint environment, which allows SharePoint to track user credentials throughout the farm - http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/07/22/whitepaper-configuring-kerberos-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-and-sql-server-2008-r2-products.aspx
3. Yet another alternative, don't use SharePoint as your application host.  Create your web application and deploy it as its own website (http://mysupercoolsite.organization.com), and in SharePoint create a new "web part page", with a "full page vertical" layout.  Then, add a "Page Viewer" web part to the page, supplying the url to mysupercoolsite.organization.com.  This way, SharePoint is a "portal" to this application for your users, but all authentication, authorization, and structure are based on the application itself, and not at all in SharePoint.

Comment: As a side-note to #3, this would mean you could write the site in MVC if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I´ve forgotten to lookup. The my approach on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

We have stayed at sharepoint as application host.

I´ve implemented a Custom UserControl which implements all the security questions.

```
public partial class FMD_RoleEnabledControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string EnabledRoles { get; set; }
    public bool HasDataBinding { get; set; }


    public string CurrentUserName
    {
        get { return Page.User.Identity.Name; }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!HasDataBinding)
            Visible = EnabledRoles.Split(',').Any(rolle => new FMDRoleProvider().IsUserInRole(CurrentUserName, rolle));
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(HasDataBinding)
            Visible = EnabledRoles.Split(',').Any(rolle => new FMDRoleProvider().IsUserInRole(CurrentUserName, rolle));
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

Custom-RoleProvider

```
public class FMDRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public const string SEPERATOR = ",";

    ...

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        if (username == null || username == "")
            throw new ProviderException("Kein User-Name übergeben"); //TODO

        string tmpRollen = "";

        RechteManager rm = new RechteManager();
        var rollen = rm.GetUserRollen(username);
        foreach (var rolle in rollen)
        {
            tmpRollen += rolle.ROL_Name + SEPERATOR;
        }

        if (tmpRollen.Length > 0)
        {
            //Letzten seperator entfernen
            tmpRollen = tmpRollen.Substring(0, tmpRollen.Length - 1);
            return tmpRollen.Split(',');
        }

        return new string[0];
    }

    ...

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string userName, string roleName)
    {
        if (userName == null || userName == "")
            throw new ProviderException("User name cannot be empty or null."); //TODO
        if (roleName == null || roleName == "")
            throw new ProviderException("Role name cannot be empty or null."); //TODO

        RechteManager rm = new RechteManager();
        return rm.IsUserInRolle(userName, roleName);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public partial class CustomControl: FMD_RoleEnabledControl

<custom:CustomControl ID="custom" runat="server" EnabledRoles="Admin" HasDataBinding="True" />
```

Its only the first approach to check against roles, but it works very well. As a second target i am going to implement extra security stuff like checking against speficic actions. Also the RoleProvider has to be registered in web.config. But time is short ;)